# Limiting records returned in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a one to many relationship between 2 tables and I would like to be able to limit how many records I return from the many table for each record in the one table.

RELATIONSHIP
tcontributors.CONTRIBUTOR_ID one or more records in table tclips.FK_CONTRIBUTOR_ID

I know this should be straight forward and it is using "TOP" in MS Access but I just can't work out the SQL for MySQL. Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I have at the moment...

```
select *
from tcontributors as qconts
inner join (SELECT * from tclips limit 3) as qclips
where CONTRIBUTOR_ID In (1922,2034,2099)
```

Comment: You want the `limit` clause, documented at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you might as well answer it like that... I'll vote it.

Comment: @dystroy He's trying a limit, but the join syntax is messed up.

Comment: your SQL doesn't show how the 2 tables are related. Post your table structure and you'll be more likely to get a sensible answer.

Comment: @Bohemian OP seems to understand it (see line 3)

Comment: you should add a condition to your join with `ON` syntax.

Comment: You should also add an order by clause to your subquery so the limit is based on something.

Answer (score 2):

One way to limit the number of rows in a join is to do a regular join, followed by a `WHERE` clause that runs a coordinated subquery with a `LIMIT` clause, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tcontributors AS qconts
INNER JOIN tclips qclips
        ON qclips.fk_contributor_id = qconts.contributor_id
WHERE qconts.contributor_id IN (1922,2034,2099)
  AND qclips.clip_id IN (
    SELECT clip_id
    FROM tclips zclips
    WHERE zclips.fk_contributor_id = qconts.contributor_id
    LIMIT 3
  )
```

Unfortunately, the current version of MySQL does not support `LIMIT` in coordinated subqueries, producing this error message ([demo on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2f19/42)):

> This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery

Other RDBMS engines do support this functionality. For example, Microsoft SQL Server produces correct results when the query is modified to fit its syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM tcontributors AS qconts
INNER JOIN tclips qclips
        ON qclips.fk_contributor_id = qconts.contributor_id
WHERE qconts.contributor_id IN (1922,2034,2099)
  AND qclips.clip_id IN (
    SELECT TOP 3 clip_id -- Use TOP 3 instead of LIMIT 3
    FROM tclips zclips
    WHERE zclips.fk_contributor_id = qconts.contributor_id
  )
```

Here is a [working demo on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b2f19/5).

Comment: does this give the first 3 joins for each row of the main table (like I think he wants)? or does it join from just 3 rows for all rows of the main table - meaning you'll get just 3 rows back (like I think this does)? Ist spitzensparken?

Comment: @Bohemian It appears that `tclips` is OP's "many" table, and `tcontributors` is his "one" table, at least from the sample SQL that he has provided. This should return up to 9 rows, if all theee contributors 1922,2034,2099 are there, and each one has at least three clips posted.

Comment: no convinced. the inner select is a constant (evaluated once) thus limiting it to the same exact 3 rows for all join attempts. I think he wants the first three joins, but of course a *different* 3 joins, for every row in tconts.

Comment: @Bohemian You're right, the inner `SELECT` was uncoordinated, so the original code might have returned nothing at all! Thanks for the correction.

Comment: +1 *now* we're talking, except you don't need to `on` clause anymore - just cross join it. same result (I think)

Comment: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'qconts.CONTRIBUTOR_ID' in 'where clause'. I also tried where with tcontributors.CONTRIBUTOR_ID in where clause same error.

Comment: @KevinGibney Try `qconts.CONTRIBUTOR_ID` to see if it fixes things. If it does not, it would be very helpful to see the structure of your tables - at least their primary and foreign keys.

Comment: Have edited question and added images to show table structure. As mentioned have tried both  'qconts.CONTRIBUTOR_ID' and 'tcontributors.CONTRIBUTOR_ID' but same error message.

Comment: @KevinGibney I worked out the syntax that has the correct logic. Unfortunately, MySQL does not have support for it yet. Other engines do support it, so if switching your database engine is an option at this stage of the project, you may want to give it a thought.

Comment: Cheers for that I'm afraid switching database engines not an option. I have latest version of MySql. I'm sure there must be a solution as it seems like something that would be used a lot. I will keep looking, but cheers for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer...

```
SELECT tcontributors.CONTRIBUTOR_ID, tcontributors.CONTRIBUTOR_NAME,c1.CLIP_ID, c1.CLIP_TITLE
FROM tcontributors
INNER JOIN tclips c1 ON c1.FK_CONTRIBUTOR_ID = tcontributors.CONTRIBUTOR_ID AND c1.FK_CONTRIBUTOR_ID IN (2731,3531,3371)
LEFT JOIN tclips c2 ON c2.FK_CONTRIBUTOR_ID = c1.FK_CONTRIBUTOR_ID AND c2.CLIP_ID < c1.CLIP_ID 
GROUP BY tcontributors.CONTRIBUTOR_ID, tcontributors.CONTRIBUTOR_NAME, c1.CLIP_ID,  c1.CLIP_TITLE 
HAVING (COUNT(c2.CLIP_ID) < 2)
ORDER BY tcontributors.CONTRIBUTOR_ID DESC, c1.CLIP_ID DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query you are not ordering subquery results, so you just need limit random `clip_id` per `fk_contributor_id` so my query does it. If you need specifically some `clip_id` you must write in that order to take them.

I think you can use this query with a little modification:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2f19/52)**

```
SELECT qclips.*,
@row_num := IF(@prev_value=qclips.fk_contributor_id ,@row_num+1,1) AS RowNumber,
@prev_value := qclips.fk_contributor_id 
FROM tcontributors AS qconts
INNER JOIN tclips qclips
        ON qclips.fk_contributor_id = qconts.contributor_id,
      (SELECT @row_num := 1) x,
      (SELECT @prev_value := '') y
WHERE qconts.contributor_id IN (1922,2034,2099)
AND IF(@prev_value=qclips.fk_contributor_id ,@row_num+1,1) < 4
ORDER BY contributor_id
```

Result without row number:

```
| CLIP_ID | FK_CONTRIBUTOR_ID | CLIP_TITLE |
|---------|-------------------|------------|
|       5 |              1922 |       five |
|       2 |              1922 |        two |
|       3 |              1922 |      three |
|       4 |              1922 |       four |
|       1 |              1922 |        one |
|       6 |              2034 |        six |
|       7 |              2034 |      seven |
|      11 |              2099 |         go |
|       8 |              2099 |        all |
|       9 |              2099 |       good |
|      10 |              2099 |   children |
```

Result with row number:

```
| CLIP_ID | FK_CONTRIBUTOR_ID | CLIP_TITLE | ROWNUMBER | PRRW |
|---------|-------------------|------------|-----------|------|
|       2 |              1922 |        two |         2 | 1922 |
|       3 |              1922 |      three |         3 | 1922 |
|       1 |              1922 |        one |         1 | 1922 |
|       6 |              2034 |        six |         1 | 2034 |
|       7 |              2034 |      seven |         2 | 2034 |
|       9 |              2099 |       good |         2 | 2099 |
|      10 |              2099 |   children |         3 | 2099 |
|       8 |              2099 |        all |         1 | 2099 |
```